# Powering a chain of 5volt sensors across 25 meters

Tags: power, dc

I have 150 pcbs which are positioned across a 25 meter duct, each consuming 30mA maximum, how should I power them?
A pair of 24v wire and 7805 on each board will be fine? With decoupling caps? 
Every 24 pieces also has a controller with rs485, so the ground should be common also? Or no?!

Comment: Why supply them with +24 V?  You'll drop 19 V across the regulator, and with 150 x 0.03 A you'll dissipate almost 86 W as waste heat.

Comment: I can supply anything, but 24 volts is already in the system for other purpose! I was afraid of voltage loss  along the way, Maybe 12 volts is better choice, so I will have enough voltage at regulator and not so much waste. Right?

Answer (score 0):

That is only 5 amps. A 0.1 ohm piece of wire, assuming a uniform distribution of current has an average load of 2.5 amps ( and this **is** a linear system), will have only 0.25 volts drop.

Pick a wire size that had 0.05 ohms over 25 meters, and the worst case drop, at the far end, is only 0.125 volts which is well within tolerance of embedded systems VDD.

Standard house wire --- AWG 12 ---- has 1.6 ohms per thousand feet or 300 meters.
Or 0.16 ohms per 30 meters. At 50 degree. Simply set the system VDD 0.2 volts high.
Or 0.4 volts, because the Ground wires will have the same IR drop.

Thus get thee to a hardware store and buy a small roll of standard SOLID 12 gauge wire.

Remember your GROUND voltages will differ, by 0.2 volts, along the distance.

Comment: I have space limitation, and maximum cable size I can use is AWG14 or 2.5mm, then what will be your suggestion for input voltage? I need stable 5 volts at controller. Sorry I did not mention that before

Comment: Then you need to supply a high voltage along the DUCT, and use a Switching Regulator at each node. How will the data be transported? by radio? or in wires? What is the GROUND?  A wire?  a thin wire? That will have the same I*R voltage drop.

Comment: Supply the power from the MIDDLE. Half the resistance and half the current.

Comment: Ground will be common, with same cable size, data is transported by rs485 half duplex, (Max485). now it comes another point... The ground would be the same for both voltage levels. Right? I have possibility to connect it also to an earth connection. Please advise.

Comment: Your system has some noise immunity, because logic circuits have about 30% of VDD as their noise margin. Thus 0.2 volts of ground variation should not be a problem. Set your slewrates to SLOW.